# Error while passing DBNull to SqlParameter

Tags: c#, sql-server-2008-r2, .net-4.0

I am trying to pass null value to `SqlParameter` if the value of variable `vName` is null, else pass `vName` value as shown below

```
cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@NAME", SqlDbType.VarChar)).Value = vName ? null : DBNull.Value;
```

but I get an error

> Cannot implicitly convert type 'string' to 'bool'

I searched and found that I have to use `AgeItem.AgeIndex` but I got error that says

> The name 'AgeItem' does not exist in the current context

```
cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@NAME", SqlDbType.VarChar)).Value =(object)AgeItem.AgeIndex ?? DBNull.Value;
```

Comment: md.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@NAME", SqlDbType.VarChar)).Value = vName ? vName : DBNull.Value; is it a spelling mistake? u didnt pass vname

Comment: @Naruto I did not get it

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`vName` is a string but you use  it like it was a `bool`: `vName ? ...`. Use `vName == null ? ...`:

```
cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@NAME", SqlDbType.VarChar)).Value =
     vName == null ? DBNull.Value : (Object)vName;
```

Answer (score 1):

IMHO much cleaner:

```
if (vName != null)
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@NAME",vName);
else
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Name",null);
```

Comment: PS. If the command is a Stored Procedure and can accept a null value then the else and subsequent lines are not necessary.

Answer (score 0):

Code should be change as follow

```
cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@NAME", SqlDbType.VarChar)).Value!= null ? vName: DBNull.Value;
```

Comment: error -> Type of conditional expression cannot be determined because there is no implicit conversion between 'string' and 'System.DBNull'